# How i can use 1 login for multiple project laravel angular using jwt

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

example :
project name :
1. CarMaintenanceProject.
2. BikeMaintenanceProject.
3. MotorcycleMaintenanceProject.

i want 1 login for every project, but can access multiple project without more login, example i successfully login in BikeMaintenanceProject and then i will acces MotorcycleMaintenanceProject without login.

Comment: If I get your question right, I would probably just put those 3 projects together using namespacing for everything else but user management.

Comment: sorry sir, but im going to put the role on each project, not in global project. i want to use 1 login for multiple project. just using 1 user table for login on multiple project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to create 4 projects.

1 project for the login/Single Sign On (SSO). This project will hold your `users` table and an API for authentication (JWT/Passport/etc.).

Then from any project, when user submits users details, you send them to the SSO project via API and gets a response if the login was successful. The SSO should return a token to the project from which the user is logging in.

You can learn more about Laravel Passport and token grants here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

You mentioned using JWT, here are some resources to get you started:
https://dzone.com/articles/from-json-web-token-to-single-sign-on-part-1-creat-1

[Single sign-on flow using JWT for cross domain authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723033/single-sign-on-flow-using-jwt-for-cross-domain-authentication)

Good luck mate!

Comment: ohh... right, Can u give me example or reference sir please, im using jwt angular.

Comment: Any updates on this? Would you recommend using Passport instead of JWT tokens?