# How to create a self signed certificate for authentication in dotnet?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, self-signed-certificate

**Background:**

We have to implement a custom authentication mechanism for identifying and authenticate my client's applications and initial details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177721/what-are-the-different-ways-to-authenticate-two-different-server-securely-apart).

Finally, We have come up with the conclusion that we will simply use self-signed certificate for encryption and decryption of JWT token.

**Now I'm figuring out the answers of following questions:**

> *Are there any dotnet libraries available for creating self-singned certificate or I should write my own code for the same?*
>
> If I would be issuing a self-singned certificate to my different clients for the secure authentication and communication then how that certificate would be updated at client machine after an expiry?

Edit:

The client needs to sing JWT token using the issued certificate before sending it back to my application.

Comment: Why do you encrypt the JWT token? That's not how it's supposed to work.

Comment: JWT token should be send via secure transport layer.

There is no point of encrypting or decrypting it.

Comment: I will not encrypt/descript JWT token instead client needs to sign JWT using issued certificate and then send it back to my application. any thought?